# Hide the domain name on Sharepoint site

Tags: domain, workspace

On my Sharepoint document workspace site the users are able to publish files, news and tasks. Whenever a user for example publish a news post, the author name is displayed as DOMAIN\Username.

Is there any way I can hide the domain name from the author description? I want the site to show only Username.